# Multiline Equation and Pagebreak: align* not working

Tags: equations, align

I'm new to latex – I just want to generate a paper for my physics class. 
I have a derivation of an equation I need to split onto multiple lines but keep getting this error. I thought using an

```
\begin{align*} 
    \displaybreak[4]\\
\end{align*}
```

would work. But I get the error:

```
! Package amsmath Error: \displaybreak cannot be applied here.
l.110   } \displaybreak[4]
```

Here's my code, which I thought would work

```
\begin{align*}
  \vec{r} &= \|\vec{P}(\theta_j) - \vec{P}(\theta_i)\| \\
  &= \|(R\cos\theta_j, R\sin\theta_j) - (R\cos\theta_i, R\sin\theta_i) \\
  &= R \sqrt{
    \cos^2\theta_j -2 \cos\theta_j\cos\theta_i +  \cos^2\theta_i
    + \sin^2\theta_j -2 \sin\theta_j \sin\theta_i +  \sin^2\theta_i
  } \\
  &= R\sqrt{
    1-\sin^2\theta_j +1-\sin^2\theta_i  +  \sin^2\theta_j +  \sin^2\theta_i
    -2(\cos\theta_j\cos\theta_i+ \sin\theta_j \sin\theta_i)
  } \\
  &= R\sqrt{
    2-2(\cos\theta_j \cos\theta_i + \sin\theta_j \sin\theta_i)
  }\\
  \displaybreak[4]\\
  &= R\sqrt{
    2-2(\cos(\theta_j-theta_i))
  } \\
  &= R\sqrt{
    2-2(1-2sin\cos(\theta_j-theta_i))
  } \\
  & = 2R\sin\frac{\theta_j}{2}\\
  \therefore \vec{r} &= 2R\sin\left(\frac{\theta_j}{2}\right)
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the directive `\allowdisplaybreaks` and let LaTeX decide where it will cut the displayed equations?

Comment: I did that in my preamble. Please please respond soon. This is due tomorrow.

Comment: Why do you typeset squares and square roots with unicode symbols? (La)TeX was designed for typesetting stuff like this: `x^{y}` will typeset `x` to the power of `y` and `\sqrt{x}` will typeset the square root of `x` using the proper font.

Comment: @null: I think this addresses my answer. I forgot to check the code. The reason is  I have an editor which displays  some unicode characters to have a better readibility of the contents of formulae (a sort of pretty-printing), yet saves in traditional code so there's no problem with the compiler. The answer is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you want on my system. It took the liberty to use the `\vv` command for vectors (from package `esvect` to have nice vector arrows) and to correct some typos (missing backslashes). In my opinion, this computation could be shortened, and I don't see the necessity of the last line, just to add a pair of parentheses.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[b]{esvect} %
\usepackage{lipsum}%
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{align*}
  \vv{r}            & = \|\vv{P}(\theta_j) - \vv{P}(\theta_i)\|                                     \\
                    & = \lVert(R\cos\theta_j, R\sin\theta_j) - (R\cos\theta_i, R\sin\theta_i)\rVert \\
                    & = R \sqrt{                                                                    
  \cos^2\theta_j -2 \cos\theta_j\cos\theta_i + \cos^2\theta_i
  + \sin^2\theta_j -2 \sin\theta_j \sin\theta_i + \sin^2\theta_i
  } \\
                    & = R\sqrt{                                                                     
  1-\sin^2\theta_j +1-\sin^2\theta_i + \sin^2\theta_j + \sin^2\theta_i
  -2(\cos\theta_j\cos\theta_i+ \sin\theta_j \sin\theta_i)
  } \\
                    & = R\sqrt{                                                                     
  2-2(\cos\theta_j \cos\theta_i + \sin\theta_j \sin\theta_i)
  }\\
                    & = R\sqrt{                                                                     
  2-2(\cos(\theta_j-\theta_i))
  } \\
                    & = R\sqrt{                                                                     
  2-2(1-2\sin\cos(\theta_j-\theta_i))
  } \\
                    & = 2R\sin\frac{\theta_j}{2}                                                    \\
  \therefore \vv{r} & = 2R\sin\left(\frac{\theta_j}{2}\right)                                       
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]